# Not able to pass data from one controller to another using segue swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `views` that I would like to pass data from one view to the next. The first view is where I have the data that I would like to pass to the next view lets call it `FirstViewController`. However `FirstViewController` is embedded in a `NavigationViewController` and the `secondViewController` lets call it `DestinationViewController`.

[image]

I have tried this logic
 IN  `FirstViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "DestinationViewController") {

        if let vc: DestinationViewController = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController {
            vc.id = id
        }

    }

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
         self.id = ((self.categorytArray.object(at: indexPath.row)as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id")as! NSNumber)
        print(self.id)
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewController", sender: self)

    }

}
```

on `destinationController` I get empty value for id.

if I change in this line

```
if let vc: DestinationViewController = segue.destination as! DestinationViewController
```

I get this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10f9b3760) to 'Name.DestinationViewController' (0x1067f7c68).
>   2019-10-11 12:52:11.535900+0530 Name[2412:94748] Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10f9b3760) to 'Name.DestinationViewController' (0x1067f7c68).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the if statement is being entered?  Add a `print` in the if statement within `prepareForSegue` to make sure it is being reached.

Comment: please debug and check condition enter in tableView didSelectRowAt in if condition and get value after check on prepareSegue method.

Comment: @ Samuel Noyes- yesi did

Comment: From your error, it is clear that the destination view controller cannot be cast to DestinationViewController.  Are you sure it is of that type?

Comment: @ Kishan Suthar - I got the correct value in FirstController

Comment: @ Samuel Noyes - yes, what should I do now??

Comment: Make sure you dragged the segue from `FirstViewController` to `DestinationViewController`. You could show a storyboard screen shot if possible.

Comment: @ Starsky - I added a photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your View Controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller you need to retrieve it from the Navigation Controller as well

Try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let nvc = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let vc = nvc.viewControllers.first as? DestinationViewController else {
        return
    }
    vc.id = id

}
```

First you retrieve the navigation controller (nvc), then you get your destination vc from it's list of child view controllers. Generally, the first controller in the Navigation Controller will be first in the array.

Also you don't need to provide a sender in your performSegue call.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewController", sender: nil)
```

You will notice that prepareForSegue has a sender parameter, but since you are accessing the information you want to pass to the DetailViewController through a class variable in your first View Controller, you're not using this sender parameter anyway.

Hope this helps